# Scroll to last floated image off screen

Tags: css, image

Scroll to last floated image off screen

Hi all

I have a demo here - http://www.ttmt.org.uk

It's just a simple list of images that are floated off screen.

The images float off screen because I have set the width of the container to allow them to float.

If I scroll to see the images it scrolls past the last image to just plank space.

How do I set the width of the container to allow the images to float but stop the scrolling at the last image.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />

      <!--css-->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/master.css" />

      <style type="text/css">
        *{
          margin:0;
          padding:0;
        }
        ul{
          width:100%;
        }
        li{
          list-style:none;
          float:left;
          margin:0 10px 0 0;
        }
        .wrap{
          padding:20px;
          overflow:auto;
          width:5000px;
          background:#eee;
        }
      </style>


      <title>Title of the document</title>
      </head>

    <body>

      <div class="wrap">
        <ul>
          <li><img src="01.jpg" /></li>
          <li><img src="02.jpg" /></li>
          <li><img src="03.jpg" /></li>
          <li><img src="04.jpg" /></li>
          <li><img src="05.jpg" /></li>
        </ul>  
      </div>  

    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: Not sure this is possible with just CSS as the wrapper needs to have a width to do what you're trying to do. Could do it with jQuery.

Comment: Alternatively, just make the wrap the correct width.

Comment: Try using `min-width` instead of `width` for the container.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.wrap {
  width: auto; 
  white-space: nowrap;
}
li {
  float: none; 
  display: inline-block
}
```

That'll do it

Comment: That works Web Owl but it puts the scroll bar on the container, is it possible to have the scroll bar on the window.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code :

```
.wrap {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #EEEEEE;
    height: 510px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 1000px;
}
ul {
    width: 3500px;
}
```

this will add the scroll to the div not to the window.

hope this will help you.

Comment: Then you can try with width and height auto white-space: nowrap; , then li display inline or inline-block. ul with width:100%

Answer (score 0):

Here's your whole html with some fixes. I just added an 'img' in the css because I don't have any images at the moment... but I would advise to set yours as well because that will prevent the styling from looking slobby if the images are not the same size. It may stretch the images... but then you resize them separately. Anycase, it's just a proposal... it's your page.
ALSO, you don't have a head opening. Make sure you add it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/master.css" />
        <style type="text/css">
            body {
                margin:auto;
            }
            ul {
                width:100%;
            }
            li {
                list-style:none;
                float:none;
                margin:0 10px 0 0;
                display: inline-block;
            }
            .wrap {
                padding:20px;
                width:auto;
                background:#eee;
                white-space: nowrap;
            }
            img {
                position: relative;
                float: left;
                border: 1px solid black;
                width: 500px;
                height: 100px;
            }
        </style>
        <title>
            Title of the document
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div class="wrap">
        <ul>
          <li><img src="01.jpg" /></li>
          <li><img src="02.jpg" /></li>
          <li><img src="03.jpg" /></li>
          <li><img src="04.jpg" /></li>
          <li><img src="05.jpg" /></li>
        </ul>  
      </div>  
    </body>
</html>
```

EDIT: Remove the "overflow:auto;" in your ".wrap". Then the scrollbar will be the web browser's scrollbar.

Comment: Check my edit at the bottom of my answer for your scrollbar issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with jquery :

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/e4BPe/)

with something like that :

```
var margin = 10; //constant
var totalWidth = 0;

$('.wrap img').each(function() {
  totalWidth = totalWidth + $(this).width() + margin;
});

$('.wrap').width(totalWidth);
```

Just get total images width by adding each image width with `foreach` and `$(this).width()`, don't forget to add the margins for every image, and finish by setting the new width to the `wrap`.

There may be easier way to do that with pure css but everything I tried didn't worked...

Hope I helped you